# Coefficients of 2D Chebyshev series in numpy.polynomial.chebyshev

Tags: numpy, scipy, polynomials

I understand that `chebvander2d` and `chebval2d` return the Vandermonde matrix and fitted values for 2D inputs, and `chebfit` returns the coefficients for 1D-input series, but how do I get the coefficients for 2D-input series?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It looks to me like this is not yet implemented. The whole of 2D polynomials seems more like a draft with some stub functions (as of June 2020).

Long answer (I came looking for the same thing, so I dug a little deeper):

First of all, this applies to all of the polynomial classes, not only `chebyshev`, so you also cannot fit an "ordinary" polynomial (power series). In fact, you cannot even construct one.

To understand the programming problem, let me recapture what a 2D polynomial looks like as a math formula, at an example polynomial of degree 2:
p(x, y) = c_00 + c_10 x + c_01 y + c_20 x^2 + c11 xy + c02 y^2
here the indices of c refer to the powers of x and y (the sum of the exponents must be <= degree).

First thing to notice is that, for degree d, there are (d+1)(d+2)/2 coefficients.
They could be stored in the upper left part of a matrix or in a 1D array, e.g. aranged as in the formula above.
The documentation of functions like [numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d) implies that numpy expects the matrix variant: p(x, y) = sum_i,j c_i,j * x^i * y^j.
Side note: it may be confusing that the row index i ("y-coordinate") of the matrix is used as exponent of x, not y; maybe the role of i and j should be switched if this is eventually implementd, or at least there should be a note in the documentation.

This leads to the core problem: the data structure for the 2D coefficients is not defined anywhere; only indirectly, like above, it can be guessed that a matrix should be used. But compared to a 1D array this is a waste of space, and evaluation of the polynomial takes two nested loops instead of just one. Also: does the matrix have to be initialized with `np.zeros` or do the implemented functions make sure that the lower right part is never touched so that `np.empty` can be used?

If the whole (d+1)^2 matrix were used, as the `polyval2d` function doc suggests, the degree of the polynomial would actually be d*2 (if c_d,d != 0)
To test this, I wanted to construct a `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial` (yes, three times polynomial) and check the `degree` attribute:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

coef = np.array([
  [5.00, 5.01, 5.02],
  [5.10, 5.11, 0.  ],
  [5.20, 0.  , 0.  ]
])

polyObj = poly.Polynomial(coef)
print(polyObj.degree)
```

This gave a `ValueError: Coefficient array is not 1-d` before the print statement was reached. So while `polyval2d` expects a 2D coefficient array, it is not (yet) possible to construct such a polynomial - not manually like this at least. With this insight, it is not surprising that there is no function (yet) that computes a fit for 2D polynomials.

Comment: Then what could we do to have this working? Did you find any related routines? They should work like 2d chebfun in Matlab.

Comment: Sadly I do not have the time to deal with this currently. Iirc I ended up using a cosine/sine solution instead of a polynomial (-> FFT). That was already mature and available for a 2D domain.

Comment: Can you post a link to an example of usage? Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I just quickly dug this. Would be glad if it helps someone, but I'm not likely to reply anymore, sorry. https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZXzf70ZW95OWrlbLHVti9UxE0C2bpAJcR0X (Note to future reader: I happen to have a lifetime plan with pCloud but no guarantees that this will be available for years to come, so do not even bother to write that the link is dead.)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, `numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.chebfit2d()` does not seems to exist. Fortunately, `numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.chebvander2d()` does exist and works as expected. The following worked for me:

```
import numpy as np

def chebfit2d(x0, x1, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None):
    a = np.polynomial.chebyshev.chebvander2d(x0, x1, deg)
    if w is not None:
        a = np.matmul(np.diag(w), a)
        y = np.matmul(np.diag(w), y)
    x, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(a, y, rcond=rcond)
    if full:
        return(x.reshape(deg[0]+1, deg[1]+1), [residuals, rank, s, rcond])
    return(x.reshape(deg[0]+1, deg[1]+1))
```

The output can directly be passed to `numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.chebval2d()`

As `numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.chebvander3d()` also exists, the 3D extension should be straightforward. As a reminder, for an optimal use, x0 and x1 should be normalized so that they fill the [-1, +1] range.

Regarding Chris' comments, yes, the total degree of the polynomial is deg[0]+deg[1] and not all the possible terms for a polynomial of this degree are present (or independent). I see no issue there.